# Laravel count with where on Query Builder with joins

Tags: mysql, laravel

Good day all, I am trying to count all records in a table but only if the table does not contain data in a specific column (deleted_at). It is a join table the table names are companies and employees. I am currently counting the records with a DB::raw but it should only count it if the deleted_at column is null. Please understand that i am a beginner.

```
public function index()
  {
    $user = Auth::user()->id;

    $companies = DB::table('companies AS c')
      ->select([
        'c.id',
        'c.logo',
        'c.company_name',
        'c.created_at',
        'c.sector',
        'c.deleted_at',
        DB::raw('COUNT(e.id) AS employee_count')
      ])
      ->leftJoin('employees AS e', 'e.company_id', '=', 'c.id' )
      ->leftJoin('company_user AS cu', 'cu.company_id', '=', 'c.id')
      ->where('cu.user_id', '=', $user)
      ->where('c.deleted_at', '=', null)
      ->groupBy('c.id')
      ->get();

    return view('account.companies.index')
      ->with('companies', $companies);
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Mysql then you could use conditional aggregation

```
$companies = DB::table('companies AS c')
  ->select([
    'c.id',
    'c.logo',
    'c.company_name',
    'c.created_at',
    'c.sector',
    'c.deleted_at',
    DB::raw('SUM(c.deleted_at IS NULL) AS employee_count')
  ])
  ->leftJoin('employees AS e', 'e.company_id', '=', 'c.id' )
  ->leftJoin('company_user AS cu', 'cu.company_id', '=', 'c.id')
  ->where('cu.user_id', '=', $user)
  ->groupBy('c.id')
  ->get();
```

In mysql when an expression is used inside sum(a= b) it will result as a boolean 0/1 so you can get your conditional count using above

Or you could use `whereNull()` method in your query

```
->whereNull('c.deleted_at')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, both methods works. just changed from c.deleted_at to e.deleted_at. Have a wonderfull day :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$employeeCount = DB::table('employees')
                ->select('companies.name', DB::raw('count(employees.id) as employee_count'))
                ->join('companies', 'employees.company','=','companies.id')
                ->groupBy('companies.id')
                ->get();
```

Comment: Your answer does not address the user's question, and contains no explanation. As well, the question is 3 years old and has an accepted answer already.